# "Unhandled promise rejection" on promise chain with catch

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm getting the exception:

> (node:1356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Cannot edit expense on issued invoice

My code uses a promise chain to update some data. It gets the database version first using `getExpense`, then checks the user is allowed to edit it (it's not been `issued`). If it has been issued, it rejects the promise, if not it continues to perform `update`, then get the updated data using `getExpense` again in order to return it.

However, when running with an 'issued' expense, the update goes through and there's the above error. Rejection with the message "Cannot edit expense on issued invoice" is expected, but why is it not being caught?:

```
  expensesModels.getExpense(expense.id)
    .then(validatedExpense => {
      if (validatedExpense.issued) {
        Promise.reject('Cannot edit expense on issued invoice');
      } else {
        Promise.resolve();
      }
    })
    .then(() => expensesModels.update(expense))
    .then(() => expensesModels.getExpense(expense.id))
    .then(returnExpense => response.json(returnExpense))
    .catch(err => errorHandling.onError(err, response));
```

I understand that this error is caused when there's not a `catch` terminating the promise chain, but I'm catching in order to reject the HTTP request in the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning the `Promise.reject` from your first `.then`.

Comment: Argh. How did I not spot that. Thanks

Comment: This seems like the right answer. Also note that you can write `then(validatedExpense => { if (validatedExpense.issued) { throw new Error('Cannot edit expense on issued invoice'); }})` not need for an else block or a new promise.

Answer (score 0):

To continue down the 'then' chain, 'promise.resolve()' is called on the returned value.

Since your first then function does not return the 'promise.reject()', 'promise.resolve()' is treated as the return value and the chain progresses without the error being caught.